# Verbs ending in "-ed"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, conjugación

What kind of conjugation is it when a verb ends in:

> "-ed", such as "tened," "ved," or "coged"

What does it make the word mean/how is it used (in what context)?

(Just for the record, I've seen this tense while reading more literature works and was never something I was taught; I know there are also "-ad" endings for -ar verbs as well)

Answer (score 8):

Conjugated words ending in -ed and -ad are the imperative form of verbs of you in the *vosotros* form:

> **Imperativo:**
>
> (yo) -
>
> (tú) ten
>
> (usted) tenga
>
> (nosotros) tengamos
>
> **(vosotros) tened**
>
> (ustedes) tengan
>
> (vos) tené

This is used only in Spain, in the Castilian dialect but it can be understood in all the Spanish speaking world. There are lots of books translated in Spain, and these translations go to many countries(at least in Mexico most translations come from Spain).

The translation will be:

> Tened esto - take this[you]  (Imperative for two or more people).
>
> Coged esto- hold this[you]  (Imperative for two or more people).
>
> Cantad esta canción - sing this song[you]  (Imperative for two or more people).

Comment: I'd imagine too that many English works where "thou"/"thee" are used, the translation in any country would use vos reverencial, which despite being singular, also uses the vosotros endings, no?

Comment: Sounds like the Spanish equivalent of Shakespearean language.. `Taketh thy seat!`, `Eateth thy food!`

Answer (score 3):

It's the second person plural of the [imperative mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) for verbs of the second group (infinitive ending in *-er*).

It usually means an order, request, or suggestion, imparted to more than one person.

[Here](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal) you have official conjugation models for all groups, moods, and tenses.

Comment: Por mi experiencia esa terminación -ed es más usada en españa, argentina y uruguay, por lo menos en los paises caribeños no me es familiar en el uso común

Comment: @EmilioGort esa conjugación es usada sólo en España, que es donde se usa el *vosotros* como segunda persona del plural. En Argentina y Uruguay se usa *ustedes*, al igual que en el resto de Latinoamérica.

Answer (score 0):

The -ed and other Castilian second-person forms exist in the new world, but they are considered classical Spanish. The Bible, for example, preserves them even in the 1995 revision. They're also sometimes used when using a mock-formal tone.

Answer (score -2):

In that case those verbs with "ed" ending are in present tense (tiempo verbal presente) of the imperative mode (modo imperativo), but this conjugation is not used nowadays. Actually the imperative mode isn't either used nowadays, that's why you don't listen to anybody to use it, it comes from the past years in the Spanish literature.

Comment: Verbs with *-ed* ending stand for the past simple tense with regular verbs, also for adjectives.

Comment: They are talking in spanish not in english!!!! I'm spanish I think I speak and write good in spanish. That's why my answer is correct so if you down vote  I think you should correct that!